# How to disable ExceptionFilterAttribute coming from external source in .Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ExceptionFilterAttribute coming from external source(library). I want to use this library, cause of it has much more than that. But this filters logging(Error level) for every exception. I do not want to use error level for my business exceptions. I throws that when request has business exception(with 400 response code). How can i disable this filter with spesific Exceptions. I just want to information level log with Business Exceptions

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
  {
    private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionFilter(ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> logger) => this._logger = logger;

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
      this._logger.LogError(context.Exception, context.Exception?.Message);
      ...
    }
  }
```

i tried remove this ExceptionFilter with serviceDecorator but it could not be success. Because each single request calls Filters' constructors. So i can not remove at Startup

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize pattern matching to get this result

I have rewritten your filter to make the check if the exception is either not a HttpRequestException or if it is a non-400 http error. You can customize the check for the exact condition you  want to filter (as I do not know what the exact type you are filtering is)

```
public class GlobalExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionFilter(ILogger<GlobalExceptionFilter> logger) => this._logger = logger;

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Log if we have an exception other than a HttpRequestException or if we have an exception other than HTTP 400
        if (context.Exception is not HttpRequestException ex || (int)(ex.StatusCode ?? HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) != 400)
            _logger.LogError(context.Exception, context.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Consider the following MVC endpoints

```
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet, Route(nameof(GetLoggableValues))]
        public IActionResult GetLoggableValues()
        {
            // Logs
            throw new HttpRequestException("TEST", null, HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route(nameof(GetLoggableValues2))]
        public IActionResult GetLoggableValues2()
        {
            // Logs
            throw new SEHException("TEST2");
        }

        [HttpGet, Route(nameof(GetNonLoggableValues))]
        public IActionResult GetNonLoggableValues()
        {
            // Does not log
            throw new HttpRequestException("TEST3", null, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route(nameof(GetNonLoggableValues2))]
        public IActionResult GetNonLoggableValues2()
        {
            // Does not log, even if we hide that it is a HttpRequestException
            Exception ex = new HttpRequestException("TEST4", null, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

The first one will log as it is a HTTP 502 error.
The second one will log as it is not a HttpRequestException.
The 3rd and 4th are both HttpRequestExceptions with HTTP 400 status codes and will not log.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i can not rewrite GlobalExceptionFilter, that is external source. I am not authorized to overwrite it unfortunately

Comment: If you are unable to alter the source, I would check with the package maintainer if there’s something you can configure or if they can add it. Otherwise you will need a new library.